# Why is there a duplicate entry when this field doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql

**This is a table from Prestashop**

Why do I get this error even though 'product_default' doesn't exist?

> Duplicate entry '2971-0' for key 'product_default'
>
> INSERT INTO `psproduct_attribute` (`id_product`, `location`, `ean13`,
>   `upc`, `quantity`, `reference`, `supplier_reference`,
>   `wholesale_price`, `price`, `ecotax`, `weight`, `unit_price_impact`,
>   `minimal_quantity`, `default_on`, `available_date`) VALUES ('2971',
>   '', '', '', '0', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0',
>   '0000-00-00')

Here is the table structure:

[image]

Comment: Probably a trigger running on that table.

Comment: @juergend Nope, there aren't any triggers on the table.

Comment: What do you mean by "product_default doesn't exist"? Could you run SQL: "DESCRIBE psproduct_attribute" and paste the output? All keys will be displayed.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I've updated my post for you.

Comment: You have composite key `id_product` and some other column. There is no Auto Incrementation and such key `2971 - 0` already exists, so you are not allowed to insert one more.

Comment: so... how do I fix this? I don't totally understand what you mean...

Comment: Since that table structure and the controller that's importing them has been the same for months, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `id_product` had the `UNIQUE` key assigned to it. I had to remove this and now it inserts correctly.

Comment: For future reference, `product_default` is the name of the key, not the field.